# Награждений или награждён?

Tags: дефект, локализация, профиль-участника

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf?tab=activity&sort=badges

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В оригинале там **awarded** (награждён).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Концы идут [отсюда](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305581/339911). Нельзя сделать сразу нормально. Должно пройти ещё 2-3 года :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ sad =/